# Global Java Servlet Filter, is it possible?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlet-filters

I'm writing a project for academic purposes which among other irrelevant stuff, includes writing a filter which monitors servlet/jsp response times.

The thing is that the filter should work on every deployed web application in the server and not only over a specific one, I just couldn't find any information regarding applying "global" filters.

Is it even possible?

NOTE:
It's important to mention that i'm using **Apache Tomcat** 7 as the server of choice.

Thanks!

Mikey

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could provide the filter in Tomcat's common classpath and edit Tomcat's own `/conf/web.xml` to add the filter, but this does not run on non-existing webapp contexts (i.e. it does not cover **all** possible requests) and it is overrideable in all deployed webapps. The more robust solution depends on the servlet container used. In case of Tomcat, you need [the Valve component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html).

Kickoff example:

```java
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

public class MyValve extends ValveBase {

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // ...

        getNext().invoke(request, response);
    }

}
```

register it as follows in `server.xml`:

```xml
<Valve className="com.example.MyValve" />
```

Comment: What about adding the right <filter> declarations in the tomcat /conf/web.xml? will that work?

Comment: Can also. They're only overridable whenever webapp's `/WEB-INF/web.xml` has another one with same filter name. If you can afford this risk, go ahead with putting it in Tomcat's `/conf/web.xml`. Valves are in no way overridable/disableable from the webapp side on.

Comment: Last question - where should the compiled Filter code be placed using either one of the above methods (valve or filter)?

Comment: In the common classpath of Tomcat. Either just as JAR straight in `Tomcat/lib` or in a path as represented by `common.loader` property in `/conf/catalina.properties`.

Comment: From my expirience filter declared in conf/web.xml are executed AFTER all filters defined in webapp

Answer (score 0):

Filters are  configured per-web app, but Tomcat itself may have a mechanism for timing request/response processing times.

Answer (score -2):

You can config the url-pattern of your filter to process any request/response that you want. Please check http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/config/webapp.xtp#filter-mapping

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the OP's question at all. He specifically mentioned that he wanted something that would apply to all webapps on a given Servlet container.