# tomcat filter for all webapps

Tags: java, tomcat

Problem: i want to do filter for all webapps.

I created a filter for monitoring requests to the apache tomcat server.

for the sake of example, it's called MyFilter. i created it in netbeans, which created 2 separated directories:

```
webpages - contains:
    META-INF
    WEB-INF
    index.jsp (a file which i created for viewing monitored data)

source packages
    my.package/MyFilter
```

in the same when i execute it from netbeans, it deploys it and sends me to http://localhost:8080/MyFilter

whenever i view a page under /MyFilter/somepath - it runs the filter.

i want the filter to run on all paths, and not only for the webapp

Where do i need to locate the project files? which project files do i need? should i edit conf/web.xml and add the filter? or should i only be in the specific webapp's web.xml?

**EDIT:**

i copied the generated .war file into tomcat/webapps

when i start tomcat, it creates a directory (tomcat/webapps/MyFilter/)

i added the filter into tomcat/conf/web.xml. when i start it, it fails to load ://localhost:8080/ but successfully loads (and filters) ://localhost:8080/MyFilter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global Java Servlet Filter, is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630268/global-java-servlet-filter-is-it-possible)

Comment: @BalusC, im aware of valve, but can it be done with filter?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you just need to fix the filter's URL pattern in Tomcat's `web.xml`?

Comment: it's set to /* , shouldn't it be for all requests?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps your problem is caused because you don't have a webapp on the ROOT at all? Filters runs on deployed webapps only. You asked how to have a global filter for **all** webapps.

Comment: @BalusC, i have tomcat/webapps/ROOT. i copied the build/web from my project into tomcat/webapps/MyFilter

Comment: Then it's maybe not present in the right location in the classpath and not loaded at all. Read startup logs of ROOT webapp.

Comment: under server.xml, if <Host unpackWARs... is set to true, it will unpack the .war file into a directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A filter will *by definition* only ever run within the web application it is defined in.

You could define it in the `web.xml` in the `conf/` directory of Tomcat to have it included in all web applications deployed to that Tomcat by default (note that you'd also need to make the filter class available to all web applications, probably by putting it in the `lib/` directory of Tomcat).

Alternatively, you can implement a [Tomcat Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html), which is conceptually similar to a filter, but can be installed on an Engine, Host or Context in Tomcat.

Comment: thanks, but in my case i have do implement it using a filter. i added it to web.xml, and it loads on apache startup, but still it seems to run the filter command only for /MyFilter paths. i located the build/web/* in webapps/ directory btw. what am i missing?

Comment: To **which** `web.xml` did you add it? The one of your web application? Or to the one in the `conf/` directory of your Tomcat installation?

Comment: both. i think the problem is that in the conf/web.xml i need somehow to specify a different path for filter-class

Comment: @Liorsolo: did you ensure that the filter class is actually on the classpath of all applications? Did you put it in a JAR (with all it's dependencies!) and put that into Tomcats `lib/`?

Comment: it generates a war file instead of a jar. tomcat's lib contains only jars

Comment: @Liorsolo: is there actually a web application on the path you want the filter to trigger on? If not, then you *either* need to run one there (or in the ROOT context) *or* use a Valve, as posted in the other question.

Comment: The problem with filter in defined in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml is that it will be last in filter chain. So, for example you can't use it for timing or auth requests