# Do I need to separate web service servlet and mvc servlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

My application serves as a SOAP web service and also processes web requests. This is my config for my web service.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I enter my web service URL on browser I can successfully see that my web service is running by viewing the

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
...
</wsdl:definitions>
```

but when I send a request from SoapUI I get an error 404 page not found. How can I fix this?

**Edit:** According to [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) Spring WS uses a different servlet type for handling SOAP messages: MessageDispatcherServlet. By naming this bean messageDispatcherServlet, it does not replace Spring Boot’s default DispatcherServlet bean. In my case I the default DispatcherServlet is the one handling POST requests from SoapUI. When I send GET requests, messageDispatcherServlet indicates that my WS is running normal. This is what I assume is causing the problem. I checked this on the log when I send a request from browser to my Web Service URI.

```
Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'messageDispatcherServlet'
FrameworkServlet 'messageDispatcherServlet': initialization started
Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
FrameworkServlet 'messageDispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
```

**Edit 2:** I would also like to add that I am using Spring Web Security. After doing a couple of tests with a new spring producer, I realized it stopped working after I added Spring Web Security from the dependencies. I am wondering if this is what may cause my request to he handled by the DefaultDispatcherServlet.

**Edit 3:** I can confirm that this is caused by spring web security. I am still working how to fix it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the web server (tomcat if you are using the default) has been mapped to serve both requests. That is why the browser shows the service. Have you looked at filtering?

Comment: @efekctive do you have any good examples I can check for filtering?

Comment: tangled up now. I will get back to in a bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808544/tomcat-filter-for-all-webapps

Answer (score 0):

You do not need separate servlet class, you just need to register it. 
Try to instantiate your webservice the following way

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
@ComponentScan("com.mypackage") 
public class AppConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema mySchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("portname");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://localhost/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(mySchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
    @Bean
    public XsdSchema mySchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("mySchema.xsd"));
    }
```

WebAppInitializer class

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new 
                            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
appContext.register(AppConfig.class);  
appContext.setServletContext(servletContext);    
MessageDispatcherServlet msgServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
msgServlet.setApplicationContext(appContext);
msgServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",servlet);  
dynamic.addMapping("/ws/*");  
dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
}
```

Comment: I do not understand this and it doesn't really work.

Comment: What kind of problem do you face, please elaborate.

Comment: Nothing changes. Same situation when I add this class.

Comment: Are you able to test it from browser?

Comment: Yes, as indicated before, I get a response when I send request from browser.

Comment: Can you upload your project for evaluation?